# How to disable "Welcome back!" message upon document open in Microsoft Word (macOS)?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, popups

Suddenly today, when I open a Word doc, I'm greeting with an irritating "Welcome back!" message that points strangely to the right edge of the screen.

[image: screenshot of popup]

When I hover it, the text content changes to "A few seconds ago" (or presumably whenever I last opened the document). When I click it, it disappears and scrolls the document apparently to where last I viewed the page. If I ignore it, it seems only to disappear by scrolling the page.

Why does it point to the right edge of my screen (there's no UI there)? How might I disable this distraction? Thanks.

- Microsoft Word for Mac Version 16.26 (2019)
- macOS Mojave Version 10.14.5

Comment: At least it's not a paper-clip or a puppy ;)

Comment: If there is any way to disable this, I haven't found it. And yes, it is extremely annoying. Apparently, Microsoft thinks it's amusing or somehow helpful. About the only thing one can do is hotkey back to the top of the document before closing it in Word. Oh...and it does this in the Windows version, too.

Comment: There is a registry fix in Windows (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-word/disable-pick-up-where-you-left-off/d818eba4-af8f-4296-844f-abd540e41a0a), but there is nothing for Mac.

Comment: Don't click it. Press escape or just ignore it and start working.

Comment: It doesn't respond to the `esc` key.

Comment: FYI: the reason this feature exists is for accessibility for the blind.  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/disable-word-onlines-welcome-back/c1d324fb-6a94-4da3-aa18-2aa3578e61b4 I would be OK with it if it didn't keep you from using Ctrl+F until it goes away!

Answer (score 1):

I have moved the bundles

```
setupui_bundle.bundle
OUIWhatsNewBundle_mac.bundle
OfficePrefsUI.bundle
ExperimentUI.bundle
```

to the desktop and have restarted Word. It has not shown up since then. I am not sure if something elso broke, please check and give feedback. Many thanks.

Comment: Did anything else break? Anyway, having found out where the bundles were I have done the same thing and will report back. How I hate Word!